# Do I need two ESTAs if I am not leaving the airport the first time, and then staying in the US the following week?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, esta

Next week I am flying to Canada from the UK through the US. We will be stopping for one hour in Dallas, before getting a plane to Vancouver. I won't get out of the airport obviously.
The following week though, I will be flying from Vancouver to the US for one week of holiday, so then I will get out of the airport.
How can I say this on my ESTA application? It makes me choose if I am not getting out of the airport or if I do.... Does it mean I need two ESTAs?

Thanks!

Comment: an ESTA is valid for as many visits as you want during the total period.

Comment: You might need to investigate the difference between the ESTA (which gives you permission to board a plane to the US) and the visa waiver program (the ability for people from countries the US perceives as low risk of abuse to enter the country without formally requesting a visa prior to arrival). In particular, you should expect to interact with Customs and Border Protection twice, which is where you explain the two different stories.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to apply for an ESTA once, an ESTA is valid for 2 years before you have to apply for a new one.

Your ESTA just authorises you to travel to the United States. When you get to the border you will tell them your connecting to Vancouver and they will enter you on the Visa Waiver Program(VWP).

When you leave Vancouver your ESTA will allow you to fly into the USA again. When you enter the USA the second time you will tell them you are coming on holiday for a week, they will again enter you on the VWP.

On the ESTA form for address in the USA I would just put the airport you are using to transit to Vancouver.

You may want to read more about ESTA and the VWP [here](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/application.html?execution=e2s1).

Comment: If it's possible to indicate "transit" in the address, that would be a good idea, too.  For example, "In transit to Vancouver via LAX" or something like that.  I've never submitted an ESTA application, so I don't know whether this would be possible.

Comment: @phoog Im not 100% I think you have to pick a state from a drop down if my memory serves me correct. Just suggested that incase it needs all fields filling. I know its not the most important thing as you don't have to update it each time you use the ESTA and you put your US address on the landing card anyway

Comment: Since the OP is going to be staying in the US at some point during the trip I might prefer to check "no" to the transit question and provide the US address for the first night he'll be staying there. From the point of view of US immigration the whole thing is probably one trip to the US (on a single I-94) that includes a side trip to Canada, so the first entry isn't strictly a transit. On the other hand I suspect the address question is a useless legality, so it likely doesn't matter much what he puts.